# Nexus DB Assertion failure

Tags: sql, nexusdb

NexusDB: Query1058317796: Query execution failed: 
Unexpected exception object raised: [EAssertionFailed] Assertion failure (C:\DSN\WIN\lib2006\Fontes\Externos\NexusDB2\nxsrBufferManager.pas, line 1115) [$3CA1/15521]

i tried this sql `SELECT * FROM "Operaca", "Pessoas"`
Many joins dot not work in my database!!!

help!!

Comment: I do not know what, but i restart the server and the problem end.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting from multiple tables without explicit joins results in cross joins, which very quickly exhausts available RAM. Google "sql join tutorial".